# How to reparent a stream in a bash script

Tags: perforce

How can I script reparenting a development stream from one mainline to another?
I have only used the GUI so far and never scripted with p4 before.

We manually perform this in the GUI by drag and drop, which is greatly explained here: https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/vcs/reparenting-streams

As I understand it the page does not explain how to do it in command line extensively:

> To reparent a stream, you simply drag and drop the stream to a new
> parent in the Stream Graph. Alternatively, you can edit the parent
> stream field in the stream settings through the GUI dialog or directly
> in the stream spec from the command line.

I have tried to search the forums for this and cannot find it.

Example:

```
dev_stream=//depot/development/cur_dev
src_stream=//depot/main/stable
dst_stream=//depot/upgrade/latest
```

Stream hierarchy:

```
dev_stream is a development stream
src_stream is a mainline stream
dst_stream is a mainline stream

dev_stream is a child of src_stream
```

I want to reparent dev_stream to dst_stream in a **script**.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: Can you explain further what you're trying to accomplish by reparenting?  Are you trying to repurpose `dev_stream` and discard whatever you did with it before, or do you want to merge the `src_stream` and `dst_stream` changes, or...?  (I ask because JUST changing the parent is not very useful and can easily be harmful, so I assume there's some larger context and problem that this script is trying to solve.)

Comment: In particular, reparenting from one mainline stream to another sounds like something that should not be a standard workflow...

Comment: @Samwise I have not decided this workflow and I'm new to the job so I really can't question it...
They try to do this to update an external depencency (where local modifications exists) so they can keep as much as possible of their "history" (Don't ask why... I just never understood why they do it this way, because I would not, but it is "their" way)
I'm stuck where I really have no other option but to do it this way for now.

Comment: I mean, just changing the parent is as simple as `p4 --field Parent=//depot/upgrade/latest stream -o //depot/development/cur_dev | p4 stream -i`.  But getting the actual file history to line up with that change is potentially a whole other problem, which is why I asked.